# Undefined reference error linking gssapi in Alpine

Tags: gcc, reference, linker, alpine-linux

While trying to build the following mini test program in Alpine 3.12, the linker refuses to find symbols in the supplied library. Same works fine in Centos 8.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <gssapi/gssapi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OM_uint32 major_status, minor_status;
    gss_OID_set gss_mech_set;
    int i;

    static gss_OID_desc _gss_mech_spnego = {6, (void *)"\x2b\x06\x01\x05\x05\x02"};
    gss_OID gss_mech_spnego = &_gss_mech_spnego;

    major_status = gss_indicate_mechs(&minor_status, &gss_mech_set);

    for (i = 0; i < gss_mech_set->count; i++)
    {
        if (!memcmp(gss_mech_set->elements[i].elements, gss_mech_spnego->elements, gss_mech_set->elements[i].length))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

```
$ gcc -o test -lgssapi test.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdnkIOh.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gss_indicate_mechs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
$ objdump -T /usr/lib/libgssapi.so | grep gss_indicate_mechs
0000000000020afb g    DF .text  00000000000000db  HEIMDAL_GSS_2.0 gss_indicate_mechs
00000000000242c8 g    DF .text  0000000000000180  HEIMDAL_GSS_2.0 gss_indicate_mechs_by_attrs
```

APKs installed

```
alpine-sdk
heimdal
heimdal-dev
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is because you placed the library before the object file. when the linker will scan the library , there is no needed symbol , and after the linker will scan the object file he will need `gss_indicate_mechs` but there is no library after to provide it. To resolve your problem use :`gcc -o test test.c -lgssapi`.

In general you have to place the libraries after the object files. For the libraries,  if there is no  circular dependencies, place the one that depends on the left and the one that provides the symbol on the right.In the case of circular dependencies or if you do not want to place the libraries as said previously, you will have to use the linker options start-group and end-group.

Comment: That solved it, however seems a little odd in this day and age that the order of the objects and libraries on the command line is significant. I would expect a linker to consider the symbols in all objects first and then perform the link phase

Comment: It is true that it could be interesting on one side. on the other side, imagine we have two libraries libx and liby (which we don't have the source code for) which both have a `process` function. and you need to use both `process` functions in two separate objects files, this is possible with the current way and not possible if all symbols are considered at the beginning. This is just an example I just thought of but maybe ( or probably)  there are other reasons.